# iPhone 4 "device not registered" ... need help for backing up some app data

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, beta

OK ... this is gonna be a long one. I have a iPhone 4 and I installed the iOS 5 Beta a couple of months ago. Last night when i reached for it to make a call ... I had to choose between disabling/enabling notifications ... and a few steps later ... I got a message:

"This device is not registered as part of the iPhone Developer Program. ##br####br## If you are a member of the Program, please register your device in the http://developer.apple.com/iphone/."

I plugged it into my Mac and I got an error that the software on the phone has expired and needs to be updated then while in itunes if i try to look for updates if tells me that there are no available updates and if i try to sync or back-up i get it tells me that a session cannot be started.

I could solve all of this with a restore (i guess) ... but I have some very important pictures taken with the camera+ app ... so they are not in the album (yet) ...

What can I do ?? I tried looking for file managers to get into the hone ... but I cannot get those pictures (being in a app) ...

Any ideas would be appreciated ... I'm desperate...

Comment: I haven't used the Camera+ app; does it not store new photos in the standard camera roll?

Comment: Also, I'd suggest moving this to apple.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing just heppened to me. I had to put my iPad in DFU mode and reset it with iTunes.

Some applications lost their data, some didn't. Don't know about Camera+ cause I don't have it installed.

By the way, pictures in the camera roll were not deleted. Videos were.

Answer (score 0):

A restore would not help, you need to renew your provisioning profile (or create a new one). I saw that the new profiles expire in 12 months now, before it was always 3 months only.

Comment: well ... on the same provisioning profile ... we have many devices ... and only my iphone screwed up (i was the only one who tried the beta)

Comment: When you connect your device, what does it say for expiration date?

Answer (score 0):

Since the main concern seems to be rescuing the photos before wiping the phone, you might try using the "Image Capture" program on your Mac.  This can be used to directly access camera memory cards and iPhone photos rather than importing with iPhoto if that's not working.  I'm not sure how it will behave if the app does not store photos in the standard locations (i.e., the Camera Roll).

Answer (score 0):

Well i tried to back up everything with iExplorer ... but I couldn't enter the apps folder ... so I gave up and put it in DFU and reset it with itunes ... c'est la vie ... from now on i'll back up more often ...